# What is the punchline to Tyrion Lannister’s joke about the jackass and the honeycomb?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

There are some TV episodes where Tyrion starts telling a joke about bringing a honeycomb and a jackass into a brothel, but he gets interrupted every time before he tells the punchline.

Is this joke in the book series?
Is there a punchline to it? (I am not looking for a punchline that somebody on the internet added, but a punchline from a canon source.)

Comment: I'll say right away that I've read the series more times than I'd like to admit, and this isn't a book joke that I remember.

Comment: [Asked and answered on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97534/63559)

Answer (score 32):

As far as I know Tyrion only tries to tell the joke thrice and each time is interrupted almost as soon as he begins. In season 1 episode 6, "A Golden Crown", at his trial he barely gets the opening line out of the way:

> **Tyrion:** I once brought a jackass and a honeycomb into a brothel...

Much later on in season 6 episode 8, "No One", he doesn't get much further:

> **Tyrion:** I once walked into a brothel with a honeycomb and a jackass. The madam says...

Lastly, in Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne", the scene ends with him starting it.

> **Tyrion:** I once brought a jackass and a honeycomb into a brothel.

So, the answer to "Is there a canonical answer?" is no. If you want some possibilities of what it could be I know of a few; here are a couple from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/6l85om/everythingtyrions_honeycomb_and_jackass_joke/).

> Tyrion walks into a brothel with a honeycomb and a jackass.
>
> Madame: What can we do for you?
>
> Tyrion: I need a woman to lay with, for mine has left me.
>
> Madame: Whatever for? And what's with the honeycomb and the mule?
>
> Tyrion: My woman found a genie in a bottle, and he granted her three wishes. The first was for a house fit for a queen, so he gave her this damn honeycomb. The second wish was that she have the nicest ass in all the land, so he gave her this damn donkey...
>
> Madame: And what about the third wish?
>
> Tyrion: Well... she asked the genie to make my cock hang down past my knee.
>
> Madame: Well that one's not so bad eh?
>
> Tyrion: Not so bad!? I used to be six foot three!

> I once took a honeycomb and a jackass into a brothel, and the madam asked me what I wanted. I said I would like to trade the honeycomb for a meal, and the jackass for a night with the most beautiful woman.
>
> She asked me why I did not simply eat the honeycomb. I said the same reason I want to trade the jackass, I'm tired of having the same thing every night.