# Why didn't Maester Ebrose mention Tyrion?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why didn't he mention Tyrion?

List of things Tyrion has done:

1. Hand of the King
2. Defended Kings Landing in the battle of Blackwater
3. Accused and convicted of killing King Joffrey.
4. Killed the most powerful man in the Seven Kingdoms, Tywin Lannister.
5. Hand of the Queen to Daenerys Targaryen. 
   6 Lord of Casterly Rock and Lord Paramount of the West.
6. Proposed the idea of elected monarchy.

Why didn't he mention him!

Comment: This is a direct dupe of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212827/58193) but I can't close it yet.

Comment: Yes I've flagged it. Please delete.

Comment: You can delete it yourself bu clicking on the delete button at the bottom of the question.

Comment: It's not there though

Comment: [There's no need to delete duplicate questions.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7944/31394) They serve as good signposts.